# Is there a difference between -0.0 and +0.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does Python store the sign of the value `0.0`? Is there any difference between `minus_zero` and `plus_zero` in the example below?

```
>>> minus_zero = -.0
>>> plus_zero = +.0
>>> minus_zero
-0.0
>>> plus_zero
0.0
>>> minus_zero == plus_zero
True
>>> import math
>>> math.isclose(minus_zero, plus_zero)
True
>>> minus_zero
-0.0
>>> plus_zero
0.0
>>> math.fabs(minus_zero)
0.0
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, it only does it when dealing with floats. Try assigning `-0` to something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The atan2(), divmod() and math.copysign() functions treats -0.0 and +0.0 differently.

Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

IEEE standard defines comparison so that +0 = -0, rather than -0 < +0. 
When a multiplication or division involves a signed zero, the sign is applied in computing the sign of the result.